# Namespace for a single method c++

Tags: c++, methods, namespaces

Let's say i have a header file Snake.h:

```
#include "SnakeBodyPart.h"
#include "GUI.h"
//...
```

And SnakeBodyPart.h is (among other things) :

```
#include "GUI.h"
class SnakeBodyPart {
    private :
        GUI::Orientation orientation;
}
```

And at last GUI.h :

```
class GUI {
    enum Orientation { NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST };
}
```

Now in Snake.cpp i want to do the following:

```
void Snake::turn(){
    if(bodyPart.getOrientation() == GUI::EAST){
        //do something
    else if (bodyPart.getOrientation() == GUI::SOUTH){
        //do something
    else if ...
}
```

I think you get the point. What i would like to know is: is it possible to set a namespace for a single method? Like giving the namespace GUI to `Snake::turn`, so i can just type `bodyPart.getOrientation() == EAST` ?

I'm having a few enums with different namespaces in Snake.cpp and would like to make the code more readible, by giving certain methods certain namespaces, not just *one namespace* for Snake.cpp. Is this possible?

Comment: Why include "GUI.h" twice, snake.h and SnakeBodyPart.h ? Have to be static functions, else have to instantiate objects to call them. And why namespace, use static functions. Gather all your enums in one namespace rather than a class function.

Comment: Your answer makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: Also note that you can switch(bodyPart.getOrientation()) to avoid the else-if chain.

Comment: Yeah i'm doing it with a switch in my real code, this was just on top of my head when i was at school :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that in your example, `GUI` is not a namespace but a class.

That being said, inside `turn()` you can write `using namespace GUI;` to access all identifiers in the `GUI` namespace without explicitely qualifying them. Alternatively, you can import single symbols using e.g. `using GUI::EAST;`, too:

```
void Snake::turn(){
    using namespace GUI;
    if(bodyPart.getOrientation() == EAST){
        //do something
    else if (bodyPart.getOrientation() == SOUTH){
        //do something
    else if ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm i must be confusing some things.. I thought every class had its own namespace? GUI is indeed a class, so how would i go about doing that? (to not write GUI::EAST but just EAST)

Comment: @Aerus: Yes, conceptually a class is a new name space for all the contained members. However, I was talking about the C++ construct `namespace`. If you had your enum in a C++ `namespace` you could have used the `using` statement I suggested. Consider making `GUI` a class (it's quite common to have a namespace like that which contains all the interesting enums and constants).

Comment: Aah i see. In your last sentence did you mean: Consider making `GUI` a *namespace* ? Since right now, it *is* a class. I would try to do that, but this is part of an assignment and we're not allowed to change header files we're given, so i'll try this after i completely finished my project. (damn you memory leaks keeping me from completing it)

Answer (score 1):

Since `GUI` is a class, just be clear and explicit and type out `GUI::` so everyone reading the code knows the context of what's happening. You have to write the code just once with a little extra typing, but people may have to read the code for years.

EDIT: Alternately if GUI doesn't *need* to be a class (`enum`s only), change it to a namespace and do `using namespace GUI;` in your function.

Comment: Yeah, i kind of forgot about the people who were still going to have to read my code, thanks for the remark! I'll just leave it with the `GUI::` in front of it. As for making it into a namespace, please read my edit on Frerich Raabe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is simply short human readable code and not actual resolution created by a namespace you can use a typedef or macro to achieve the desired results.

Alternately you do not need to contain your enum within a class or namespace unless you are worried about naming conflicts in which case including the header would be enough to be able to create an Orientation variable or reference the directional members of the enum directly.